# how to search for a folder in drive from controller action in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, action

I need to search for named folder in D drive from within controller action.how can i any body tell me how to do it in grails plz.

With advance thanks,

Laxmi.P

Comment: Since you're targeting Grails, did you mean to ask how to do it on the Client (Browser) side or the Server side?

Comment: I assume (s)he means on the server side. Obviously there's no way to do this using Grails on the client-side

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyController {
  def findDir = {

    String dirName = 'nameOfDirectoryToMatch'

    new File('D:/').eachDirMatch(dirName) {File dir ->

      // put the code to handle the matching dir(s) here. 
      // In this example we just print out the full path
      println dir.absolutePath    
    }
  }
}
```